# Hypothesis testing: X impact on Y

Tags: r, stata, hypothesis-testing

I am testing the Hypothesis that: (where Y = life_expectancy and X= GDP)

- Ho= GDP does not affect life expectancy.
- HA= GDP affects life expectancy.

*I already did the model building and got my regression results. To test this hypothesis do I reject/fail to reject based on the coefficient results? If it wouldn't have an impact the coefficient would be 0 and another number otherwise, right?

- Or do I get the t-stat from my regression table and do the normal hypothesis testing.

Comment: Hi: You have to hypothesize some relationship. Suppose that you assume it's linear. Then you would run a regression where life expectancy is the response and GDP is the predictor. This would assume that no other variables besides GDP effect life expectancy which is probably a stretch. Include others if you think that they could effect life expectancy also. The t-stat on GDP tells you whether GDP effects life expectancy, linearly.

Comment: Hi! Yes in effect I do have other predictors towards life expectancy, such as schooling, HIV, etc. In fact i did the linear regression already, and got the results. My t-stat is equal to -2.601 should I follow the normal procedure for the hypothesis test of (beta 1) ?

Comment: yes, but once you have other variables in the model, things get more tricky because the other predictors could be spuriously "consuming" some of the predictive power of GDP ( for example, if there's multi-colinearity ). or you could be leaving out some other important variable ? So, you have the right idea ( using a t-test on beta ) but note that what you are testing is  the effect of GDP GIVEN that the other variables are in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just look at the GDP coefficient. If 0 is in the confidence interval for this parameter estimate, fail to reject. Otherwise, reject. Similarly, if your p-value for that is smaller than your pre-specified alpha value, reject. Otherwise, fail to reject.